# Passing input values using post

Tags: php, post

I am trying to pass the value of `<input id="ids" type="hidden" name="ids" value="<?php echo $key['product_ID'];?>">` to the exchange.php page. Lets say i have `apple | 1 , orange | 2, pineapple | 3`. However, whenever i try to submit the values to another page, I am getting the 3 as the echo value of `$product`. When i try to remove the `type="hidden"`, I get the correct value but when I try to submit, it turns out to be a different value.

```
<form action="exchange.php" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <?php $query="SELECT * FROM Product" ; $data=$ MySQLi_CON->query($query); 
        foreach ($data as $key ) { ?>
        <strong>Name: </strong>
        <?php echo $productname=$ key[ 'product_Name'];?>
        <input id="ids" type="hidden" name="ids" value="<?php echo $key['product_ID'];?>">
        <strong>Status: </strong>
        <strong>Action: </strong>
        <input type="submit" value="Exchange" name="exchange_submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
        <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

## exchange.php

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$product = $_POST['ids']; 
echo $id; 
echo $product; 
exit;
?>
```

Comment: id should be unique. Currently you are setting id="ids" inside foreach, please change it.

Comment: same thing goes for id="id".

Comment: id and ids are two different thing. id is the current user ID, ids is the product ID

Comment: if you are selecting all the products then running foreach to iterate over them. That means you are going to multiple create input by the id="id" or id="ids" which is wrong.

id attribute should be unique inside whole page. we cannot assign same id to any other html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php echo $productname=$ key[ 'product_Name'];?>
//is it working not showing error
```

Comment: yes, it is working. Not showing error. Everything is working except for the $product = $_POST['ids']; Doesn't seem to display the correct output

Comment: You want multiple ids or single product id??

Comment: single product id, apple | 1 , orange | 2, pineapple | 3

Comment: but whenever for example i click on apple. It gives me id of 3

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you execute a foreach loop, it will store the last output of the Database table in the hidden input of yours, and that's why no matter any input you give, it will take 3 as the id of the product.Try using a  tag also.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the answer above solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using foreach for products so I consider you've more than one products.

but when you doing this you are overwriting the $_POST['ids'].

```
<input id="ids" type="hidden" name="ids" value="<?php echo $key['product_ID'];?>">
```

thats why its showing last `product_ID` present in table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the answer above solved my problem :)

Comment: @user3676202 no worries :)